# I have a list of world points(XYZ) and I want to show them in a openGL window

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

my points in x are between 0.25 and 1.21 , my points in y are between 3 and 4 and my points in z are between 99 and 101.
here is my vertex shader

```c
#version 330 core
// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec3 fragmentColor;
// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(){    

    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

    // The color of each vertex will be interpolated
    // to produce the color of each fragment
    fragmentColor = vertexColor;
}
```

and here is the code in c++

```cpp
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f);
// Camera matrix
glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(4, 3, -3), // Camera is at (4,3,-3), in World Space
    glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), // and looks at the origin
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
);
// Model matrix : an identity matrix (model will be at the origin)
glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
// Our ModelViewProjection : multiplication of our 3 matrices
glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model; // Remember, matrix multiplication is the other way around
glm::mat4 modelview = MVP;
```

I can also add that I am able to print a rectangle that I hard code the vertices with -1 and 1 using that Projection (note here the perspective instead of ortho)

```cpp
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

Comment: Most likely you don't look in the direction of the points. Try `glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(4, 3, -3), glm::vec3(0.75f, 3.5f, 100.0f), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));`. Note `glm::vec3(0.75f, 3.5f, 100.0f)` is a proximately the center  of your point cloud.

Comment: Thanks four your fast answer, however, I still can't see my points so I tried to change also the cam pos but still not working ... maybe you have an other idea ?

Comment: `glm::ortho(-2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f);` - see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't look towards your point cloud. The first argument of [`glm::lookAt`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#gaa64aa951a0e99136bba9008d2b59c78e) is the position of the camera and the second argument is the point you are looking at.
Hence the direction of the view is (0, 0, 0) - (4, 3, 3) = (-4, -3, 3).
If the points are in range x: [0.25, 1.21], y: [3, 4], z: [99, 101]. The line of sight doesn't intersect this volume.
Change the target of the view (*center*):

```cpp
glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(4, 3, -3), 
    glm::vec3(0.73f, 3.5f, 100.0f), 
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
```

`glm::vec3(0.73f, 3.5f, 100.0f)` is the center of your point cloud.

And you need to make sure that the center of the projection is on the line of sight:

```cpp
glm::ortho(-2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks, now I can find my points! Now, my problem is if I use 
        glm::ortho(-2.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, -4.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f);
My points in z are to close of each other because i am using the range 0->200 and my points are  only between 99 and 101.  Maybe you know one way to make it works ?

Comment: @onetwotest the z rangle is not the issue the issue is the x a nd y range. Try `glm::ortho(-0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 95.0f, 105.0f);` I think I answered your question well. It's all just a matter of math.